# VBA - Copy sheetvalues, paste to sheet with a variable name

Tags: vba, excel

I have a user form that allows people to input the date range of the series of data, which will then be later used to name the outputs from the rest of the macro. I am trying to copy all the values on the first sheet `WWOutput`, where all the data is analyzed/calculated and paste to a newly created sheet with the name of the variable `DateRange`, which will obviously change each time.

I am currently trying this:

```
Worksheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets("Calc")).Name = DateRange.Value
Worksheets("WWOutput").Range("A1:Q1000000").Copy
Worksheets(DateRange).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

The new sheet is created and the worksheet is copied but it is not copying to the one I want. If I try `.Cells` instead of `.Range` it gives me "Type Mismatch"

What am I doing wrong?

Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set ws = Worksheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets("Calc"))
ws.Name = DateRange.Value
Worksheets("WWOutput").Range("A1:Q1000000").Copy
ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

This should work for your needs.  I'm setting an object reference to the worksheet you added (called `ws`) and then setting its name to the `DateRange.Value`.  At that point it's simple enough to specify the worksheet necessary when pasting.  This way you can make use of the reference in any number of ways while working with it.  Let me know if you need any further explanation?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `.Value`

```
Worksheets(DateRange.Value).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```